# To varify documents, how documents attached and who will verify and if miners how will they verify?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, dapp-development, identity

I need a help to develop a function to check the customer's eligibility /proof of identity.

For example I am very very rich people (Practically NOT). Now i have decided to buy a big house in Las Vegas-USA through the help of Ethereum and Smart Contract. So Ethereum miner nodes will verify my account balance and check really i have enough money or not. Now for example Las Vegas city has a rule no foreigner can buy a house there only adult USA citizen can buy. So to buy a house i have to submit my passport or any other official documents that prove i am USA citizen and i am >= 18 years old.

So my question is in smart contract how can i submit my documents and who will verify my documents and how? Is it possible to attach something during conducting with smart contract?

However after attaching the relevant proving documents, who will gonna verify that documents in Blockchain (the Ethereum nodes??). And if it nodes how they will read the data from image/pdf of passport/other documents to verify.

And finally in solidity how can i accommodate this functionalities.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is not how blockchains work.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?https://proofofexistence.com/

Comment: https://stamp.io/ or this?

Comment: @Joe Have u any idea how these works???

Comment: They store the hash of a document on the blockchain with a timestamp. Rereading your question I dont think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your question is very difficult to answer because you are asking so much. I think you should try splitting your question up into several separate questions that are easier to answer